# Passing filepath of uploaded file from php to python

Tags: php, python, csv

I've been searching for an answer to this problem for a few days now with no luck.

I am running Apache 2.4, PHP7, and Python 2.7.11 under Windows 7.

The goal is for a user to upload a CSV file, execute the python script to filter unnecessary columns & output to a new .csv, then use Javascript to display the resultant file as a HTML table.

I might be doing this the long way so bear with me, my first foray into Python..

HTML

```
<form method="post" action=Upload() enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

formdata.php

```
<?php
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$pyscript = 'C:\vhosts\site\trim.py';
$python = 'C:\Python27\python.exe';
$cmd = "$python $pyscript";

exec("$cmd" . $uploaded_file);

var_dump($uploaded_file)
?>
```

trim.py

```
import csv
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1]) #thankyou @jjm
csv_f = csv.reader(f) 
outputfile = "sample.csv" #output file 


#create empty list containers of the wanted columns
manager = []
client = []
reminder_date = []
reminder_subject = []
assigned_to = []
#previously included, but not needed, total=[] can be set and filled with zip()
#total = []

#add the info to the columns
for row in csv_f:
    manager.append(row[3])
    client.append(row[5]) 
    reminder_date.append(row[6])
    reminder_subject.append(row[7])
    assigned_to.append(row[10])

#combine lists into single list total
total = zip(manager,client,reminder_date,reminder_subject,assigned_to)

#dump results to outputfile 
with open(outputfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for row in total:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

In the python script, if I replace $uploaded_file with a file path and execute locally with `python trim.py` the script runs fine and sample.csv is created, and in formdata.php var_dump($uploaded_file) returns `string(18) "C:\tmp\phpA5F2.tmp"` so as near as I can tell both elements work separately but not together.

Any help would be much appreciated, this has stumped me!

Comment: If you're passing `$uploaded_file` as an argument to the python script, you'll need to get it with `sys.argv[1]` in python.  Also I think you need a space at the end of `$cmd` in php.

Comment: Hi @jjm, thanks for the answer. I have tried `sys.argv[1]` as in `f = open('sys.argv[1]')` however it still gives no response. Re: spacing in `$cmd`, do you mean this should read `exec("$cmd "`?

Comment: You want `f = open(sys.argv[1])`.  Does the command `python trim.py <path-to-file>` work?

Comment: Thankyou, have updated accordingly. `python trim.py <file>` returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trim.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined`

Comment: Ah, my mistake: put `import sys` at the top of the python program.

Comment: @jjm - running 'trim.py' from 'cmd' now executes correctly and output file `sample.csv` is created as intended, however it is still not functioning via the php function.

Comment: Well, I would ensure that you have spaces between the program arguments passed to exec: `exec("$python $pyscript $uploaded_file")`.  Also, if you pass refs to an array and an int, you can get the output and status of the command: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I don't really know PHP well enough to help beyond that.

Comment: Thanks @jjm - I've read through the manual for the exec function and as near as I can tell everything is compliant. Hopefully someone else has encountered this scenario before and I will keep wroking on it in the meantime. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RGRWCO in the long tern just moving the logic from your Python script into PHP (or having Python handle the Web requests, either is easy) is going to be easier.